# Failed to gather analytics on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, logs

I am trying to get sysdiagnose data on iPhone. After many tries and waiting, nothing is appearing inside **Analytics & Improvements** -> **Analytics Data**.

I have followed these [guides](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose):

1. Sysdiagnose (iOS)

   - When I hold UP and DOWN volume buttons + POWER button for 1-1.5 sec, I get vibration but nothing else happen, no logs
2. iOS Sysdiagnose (Using AssistiveTouch)

   - When I click on Analytics button in AssistiveTouch, I am getting message: "AssistiveTouch Failed to gather analytics. Please try again."

After few resets situation is the same.

I am using:

- iPhone 12 Max Pro
- iOS 16.7.1

Did somebody have this issue and found a solution?